# mySQL: Bulk insert records from search result

Tags: mysql

I have a table that records the mailing list subscriptions for subscribers.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscriber_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subscriber_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_entered_gmt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `subscriber_id_account_id_list_id` (`subscriber_id`,`account_id`,`list_id`),
  KEY `list_id_account_id` (`list_id`,`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1454722 ;
```

In the application, which uses the table, there is function that allows all subscribers within a mailing list to be subscribed to another.

I was going to use a subquery to get all the current subscribers of the mailing list that will be subscribed to the new selected mailing list and some how with this list of subscribers insert a new mailing list record for each defining the new subscription but the mailing list can reach up to 250,000 subscribers so I am not sure how this should be done.

Cheers

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INSERT ... SELECT something like this -

```
INSERT INTO subscriber_list (subscriber_id, account_id, list_id, date_entered_gmt)
SELECT subscriber_id, account_id, 4, NOW()
FROM subscriber_list
WHERE list_id = 3
```

In response to your comment I have updated the values in this query. This will -

```
SELECT subscriber_id, account_id, 4, NOW()
FROM subscriber_list
WHERE list_id = 3
```

and insert them straight into the subscriber list table. So, if the values in the SELECT are those that you want to insert this will suit your scenario.

Comment: Thanks - so does the sql insert a new record for each subscriber in the current list? For example if the current list has 200,000 records that means 200,000 new records need to be added for the target mailing list with the subscribers id being different for each insert.

Comment: Whatever the SELECT part of the query returns will be inserted into the table, unless there is a key violation. If this answers your question please remember to accept the answer. Just click on the tick to the left.

Comment: Hmm still not sure if this will work. basically if the current mailing list has 200,000 subscribers subscribed to it and a client wants all the subscribers within the current list (200,000) subscribed to a new list then the sql would need to do something like this:

"Insert a new record for each subscriber in the subscriber_list table that is currently subscribed to the mailing list with id of 3."

So the table would have 200,000 new rows with each row containing the subscriber_id for each matched record and the target mailing list id - which as an example is id:: 4

Comment: Thanks - I will give it a go. I assume the SQL will out the inserts for each subscriber_id of which in this example will be 200,000 unique subscriber_id's thus 200,000 inserts all with different subscriber_id values.